# Выполнение вычислений с пользовательским вводом

Tags: python

У меня появилась проблема при попытке получить ответ . Ошибка - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'str'.

```
num1 = input("Enter а base:" )
num2 = input("Enter an exponent:" )
summar = pow(num1, num2)
print(f"{num1} to the power of {num2} = {summar}")
```

В чем ошибка ?

Comment: В том что вы передаете строки в функцию pow. А она работает с числовыми типами.

Comment: Не пишите КАПСОМ пожалуйста )

Comment: Тут рядом примерно 1357 дубликатов, но лень искать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам просто нужно за `int`-ить переменные:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter а base: " ))
num2 = int(input("Enter an exponent: " ))
summar = pow(num1, num2)
print(f"{num1} to the power of {num2} = {summar}")
```